# internship interview, best JSON structure

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

So i had this internship interview for a PHP and MySQL internship and after talking for a while they gave me some test questions to see if i got skills, dead line to answer is tonight.

I was able to solve most questions but there was three of them i couldn't figure out how to answer them, they are about JSON and API, so here they are :

- Propose a JSON structure that sends informations upon login (email and password) to an API
- Propose a JSON structure that returns a response to the previous call
- Same question as question 2, knowing that you evolve with an API

I'm really lost, isn't the JSON structure relative to how the API is expecting to receive data ?

What is the best answer i can give to those three questions ?

Comment: Personally I'd say these are weird questions. I'd need more information to actually answer these in detail.

Comment: Why did you ask this question. This has three questions which are distinct. Please check how to ask on stackoverflow

Comment: questions are related to each other, they are in the same test, i know how to ask in stackoverflow

Comment: The answer to the 3rd question is to add a version indicator so the API can be updated over time. Ex: `{ "version" : "1", "email" : "user@xyz.com", "password" : "password" }`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and edit your question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2, accepted):

These questions are valid as they most probably want to know if you are capable of designing API's. API is the interface and JSON is the interface format. The questions are regarding the format, For example a very simple login api, could be that the client must send over the following as a post request.

```
{ "email" : "user@xyz.com", "password" : "password" }
```

If the client sent a request which was not a post request, the response could be

```
{ "status" : "405", "msg" : "http method not allowed" }
```

or if the authorizarion failed,

```
{ "status" : "401", "msg" : "unauthorized" }
```

if successfull

```
{ "status" : "200", "token" : "some long crypto hash string" }
```

The token can then be used in subsequent API calls to identify the user.

Comment: those like good answers, thanks a lot, but they only answer the first two question, do you have any idea how can i answer the third one ?

Comment: I didnt answer it, becuase I dont know what the question is asking. Perhaps it is regarding flexibility and backward compatibility. I really cant be sure, as the question is not clear.

Comment: yeah it's not clear at all, maybe it's talking about two api that communicate toogether ? please help me think about it so i won't leave this question blank, thanks in advance